# Selecting specific rows in DF based on 2 columns in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have data from excel loaded into a pandas dataframe. I now want to select only those rows whose ASSESSMENT ID is the max ASSESSMENT ID per APPID and for all the UI SEQ NUMBERS for that APPID.

```
APPID   APPNAME ASSESSMENT ID   UI SEQ NUMBER   QUESTION    ANSWER TEXT .   
1   appname 2493    11  Question    No .   
1   appname 13808   11  Question    Ctry of domicile .   
1   appname 13808   11  Question    Name .   
1   appname 35316   11  Question    Ctry of domicile .       
1   appname 35316   11  Question    Name .   
1   appname 35316   11  Question    Nationality .       
1   appname 2493    12  Question    Corp name .   
1   appname 2493    12  Question    Cr Br Scr .   
1   appname 2493    12  Question    Inc And Assests .   
1   appname 2493    12  Question    Int, Ext Reg Reports .   
1   appname 13808   12  Question    Corp name .   
1   appname 35316   12  Question    Corp name .   
1   appname 2493    13  Question    No .   
1   appname 13808   13  Question    No .   
1   appname 35316   13  Question    No .   
1   appname 2493    14  Question    No .   
1   appname 13808   14  Question    firms Pos .   
1   appname 35316   14  Question    firms Pos .
```

And the result would be

```
APPID   APPNAME ASSESSMENT ID   UI SEQ NUMBER   QUESTION    ANSWER TEXT .   
1   appname 35316   11  Question    Ctry of domicile .   
1   appname 35316   11  Question    Name .   
1   appname 35316   11  Question    Nationality .   
1   appname 35316   12  Question    Corp name .   
1   appname 35316   13  Question    No .   
1   appname 35316   14  Question    firms Pos .
```

Comment: Please [Don't post images of code (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Apologies for posting the image, But there was no other way I could post the data from excel onto here without proper formatting

Comment: Hmmm, if copy paste and add 4 spaces before each row it doesnt work?

Comment: That worked. Thanks jezrael for that suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with mask created by `apply`:

```
df1 = df[df.groupby(['APPID', 'UI SEQ NUMBER'])['ASSESSMENT ID'].apply(lambda x:x==x.max())]
print (df1)
    APPID  APPNAME  ASSESSMENT ID  UI SEQ NUMBER  QUESTION       ANSWER TEXT.
3       1  appname          35316             11  Question  Ctry of domicile.
4       1  appname          35316             11  Question              Name.
5       1  appname          35316             11  Question       Nationality.
11      1  appname          35316             12  Question         Corp name.
14      1  appname          35316             13  Question                No.
17      1  appname          35316             14  Question         firms Pos.
```

Or if dont need all duplicated values use [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html):

```
df1 = df.loc[df.groupby(['APPID', 'UI SEQ NUMBER'])['ASSESSMENT ID'].idxmax()]
print (df1)
    APPID  APPNAME  ASSESSMENT ID  UI SEQ NUMBER  QUESTION       ANSWER TEXT.
3       1  appname          35316             11  Question  Ctry of domicile.
11      1  appname          35316             12  Question         Corp name.
14      1  appname          35316             13  Question                No.
17      1  appname          35316             14  Question         firms Pos.
```

Comment: Perfect jezrael. that solved it. I was doing the following -df[df.groupby(['APPID', 'UI SEQ NUMBERS'])['ASSESSMENT ID'].max()

Comment: Then better is use `df1 = df.loc[df.groupby(['APPID', 'UI SEQ NUMBER'])['ASSESSMENT ID'].idxmax()]`